# How to add the only user on a Debian system back into the sudo group?

Tags: debian, sudo, users, group, non-root-user

I'm using Debian on a headless server that I'm connecting to via ssh.

When I installed Debian, I did not create a root account, so the first user created was in the sudo group. Then I added that user to another group, but in my ignorance I used:

```
sudo usermod -G NewGroup UserName
```

instead of:

```
sudo usermod -aG NewGroup UserName
```

Without the 'a' (append), this removed the user from every group (including sudo) other than the default UserName group.

I've learned my lesson now, but is there any way to regain superuser access to this installation?

This is a test environment with nothing to backup or recover, so I can simply reformat if all is lost, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: You could setup a rescue disk image, add it to your VM to boot from, and from there proceed with your corrections.

Comment: Is the server physically accessible by you? If so you can create a live medium with ssh-access enabled, then go on to manipulate your `/etc/group` file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The server _is_ physically accessible. I can create a live usb, but will have to attach a monitor and keyboard to get it started anyway, right? (At least to get the computer to boot from USB) Or am I confused about what you mean?

Comment: You have the root password, and access to the console? Log in as root and edit the `/etc/group` file appropriately. Or is this the bit you're unsure about?

Comment: @Fiximan Your suggestion got me there. I hooked up a monitor and keyboard and booted to a live usb to edit the `group` file. If you post an answer I will give you the credit.

Comment: @roaima There is no root password. I skipped setting up a root password and went with using UserName through sudo instead. Of course, I'm still new to Linux, so I could be completely misunderstanding how this works.

Comment: The solution in the question this is marked as a duplicate of will do if you just use that root shell to fix your group membership instead of changing root's password.  So the very last bit will change, but the guts of that answer are still right here I think.

Comment: @EricRenouf This is most likely true (though I have not tested it because I fixed the problem by booting from a live installer). However, as you describe it, this means that my question and the previous question have similar (not exact) solutions. I cannot understand why two _different_ questions that have _similar_ solutions would be considered "exact duplicates" of each other. I know that you didn't mark it as a duplicate, but I'm just really confused about why this happened.

Comment: Questions don't have to be exact to count as duplicates.  I'm on the fence about this one but you can read more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/289203) about dupes. you could also ask on meta with a link to this question to try to get some clarification

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have looked through that post, though I hadn't thought of asking on meta. I did want to add that I think of StackExchange as a searchable collection of knowledge. And I did search, but couldn't find a solution. And the reason I couldn't find the solution was because I never thought to search for "forgot root password". I searched for things like "removed user from sudo group" or "how to add user to sudo group". So there's no way I (or others with this issue) could have found that solution, since any relevant searches would not pull up that question.

Comment: That's why this is marked as a duplicate and wasn't deleted, in the future others may find this and get the hint that those are basically the same problem even if they don't seem it on the surface.  Duplicate is not pejorative, it's informative.

Comment: @LvxOne (following on from [your response](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306551/how-to-add-the-only-user-on-a-debian-system-back-into-the-sudo-group?noredirect=1#comment539236_306551) to my comment): ah I see. I had read your "_I did not forget the root password_" as meaning that you knew it, not that you didn't have one in the first place. In this case the solution will be to boot a rescue disk and edit your on-disk `/etc/group` directly.

Comment: @Fiximan This was edited and reopened; can you post your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have physical access to the server, you can either create a live medium which has a headless boot routine including an ssh-server to be started and then access the server via these ssh-credentials or - the simpler approach - in case you have a monitor and a keyboard available, plug them in and simply boot into the system.

Then mount the original hard drive and edit the `/etc/group` file accordingly (i.e.: `sudo:x:<integer_number>:<username>`).

As a hint for the future: IMHO having an active `root` account (i.e. password is not locked) is not necessarily a security risk - especially if you restrict ssh-access for root.